# Why do official Olympics youtube channel in USA hiding Indian videos?

Tags: olympics

This is the screenshot of official Olympics Youtube channel from India (July 30, 2021):

[image]

Here is the official Olympic Youtube channel from USA location (July 30 2021):
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic here, as it's about the actions of a social media account, rather than actually being about sport. It's worth noting that content being restricted to certain locations is perfectly normal.

Comment: When you click on an Indian video from a US location, does it say "This video is not available in your country"?

Comment: Location blocking by YouTube and its uploaders is not an issue restricted, or even primarily relevant, to sports. It has been happening across media for decades. There is a valid on-topic question regarding the mechanics of this, as it is of interest to sports fans and those involved in the pro sports and related industries. But I do not believe this is that question..

Comment: @F1Krazy "Things of interest to fans" are in our scope, and the Olympics is probably the biggest thing of interest to fans globally so I think it's generally on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a definitive answer on why *YouTube* make the decision they make about which videos to show, you'd have to ask YouTube. Looking at the general case, there are two primary reasons why a social media account might do this:

1. The right to show certain content in certain territories. The rights to show the Olympics are enormously complicated (and expensive) - it may be the case that the rights to the Indian-specific videos do not allow them to be shown in the USA.
2. Interest of fans. There is no law which says a social media account has to show the same content in every country (at least, not in the USA). It is a perfectly valid editorial decision for whoever is managing the content on the Olympics YouTube channel to say that a video about a non-American athlete competing in a sport which is barely played in America with non-English commentary is of very low interest to American fans.

Answer (score 2):

On your first screenshot, 10 videos out of 15 are related to the Indian athletes. Do you think this is representative of what is going on in the Olympics in general?

The real question is not "Why does Youtube channel in USA hide Indian videos", but "Why does Youtube channel in India show mostly Indian videos". The answer is obvious: because that's what Indian viewers are likely to be interested in. As the other countries are concerned, India now has 1 silver and 1 bronze medal (hopefully they get more later on), this doesn't make it likely to make the front page in the USA or worldwide.